# React-Router-Dom Link not working in a nested component. Update url parameters, but component doesn't load on click. Works if I refresh after click

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I have a NavBar that's on multiple pages that allows me to search for an user. After the searching, clicking on it should re-direct me to the user page via Link from react-router-dom. The problem is this only works on the main page, and doesn't work when clicking from an user's page.

I've tried adding WithRouter to all my related components (containers, parents, and the children). Also tried fiddling with the Route pathing / exact pathing syntax to no avail.

*Removed components imports and non-relavant code for clarity.

/app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Switch,
  Link,
  HashRouter,
  withRouter,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthRoute, ProtectedRoute } from '../utils/route_utils';

const App = () => (
  <div className="main">
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        <AuthRoute exact path="/" component={LoginContainer} />
        <AuthRoute exact path="/signup" component={SignupContainer} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/feed" component={FeedContainer} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/users/:userId" component={GreetingContainer} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/posts/:postId" component={PostShowContainer} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/upload" component={Upload} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/accounts/edit" component={AccountsEditContainer} />
        <Route component={Errors} />
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  </div>
);

export default withRouter(App);
```

/greeting_container.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
...
};

const mapDispatchtoProps = (dispatch) => ({
....
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchtoProps)(Greeting));
```

/greeting.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBarContainer from '../nav_bar/nav_bar_container';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderPosts = this.renderPosts.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.user) return null;
    const profileUser = parseInt(this.props.match.params.userId)
    const user = this.props.user
    return (
      <div className="user-page-container">
        <Modal currentUser={user} />
        <NavBarContainer />
      </div>
}

export default Greeting;
```

/nav_bar_container.jsx

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './nav_bar';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
....
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
...
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavBar));
```

/nav_bar.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBarSearch from './nav_bar_search';

const NavBar = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>

              < NavBarSearch
                fetchSearchedUsers={props.fetchSearchedUsers}
                searchResults={props.searchResults}
              />
  </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

/nav_bar_search.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBarSearchResults from './nav_bar_search_results';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class NavBarSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchInput: ''
    }
    this.generateSearch = this.generateSearch.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div >
        <input className="search-bar-test" onChange={this.generateSearch}  type="text"  placeholder='Search' />
        {this.state.searchInput ? <NavBarSearchResults
          searchResults={this.props.searchResults}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
          // key={this.props.searchResults.id}
          /> : null
        }
      </div>
        )
      }
}

export default withRouter(NavBarSearch);
```

/nav_bar_search_results.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBarSearchResults = function({ searchResults, handleClick }) {
  let results = searchResults ? Object.entries(searchResults).map((result) =>
      <Link className="search-links" to={`/users/${result[0]}`} onClick={e => handleClick} key={result[0]}>
    <div className="search-results-item">
      <img className="search-results-image" src={result[1].photoUrl} />
      {result[1].username}
    </div>
      </Link>
  ) : null

  return (
    <div className="search-results-container">
      {results}
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(NavBarSearchResults);
```

Once again, it is the Link in the Nav_Bar_Search_Results.jsx file that is not working. This file is nested several levels deep starting from the Greeting.jsx file. The string interpolation I'm doing is the user_id number. Please recall that the url parameters updates and the page works if I CLICK and REFRESH page, but not on first click alone.

The correct user page should render as specified by the url parameters

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow. The following application has the same architecture as of urs. It might help.  
https://github.com/mir-nawaz/react-inspinia

Comment: Hello, could you provide a sample on https://codesandbox.io ? It's much faster to fix your issue if we can replicate it.